# Flagging employees that are late to work based off punch-in/out data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm currently working on a personal project and I am stumped. I have a sample table of data that has punch-in and punch-out data for employees at company XYZ. Here is a quick look at the table, PUNCHDTL:

[image: Snapshot of PUNCHDTL]

I would like to create a separate table that I could call PUNCH_FLAG, where I identify cases where an employee clocks in too late or too early for the start or end of their shift. All employees are supposed to start on the hour (i.e. 1:00pm, 2:00pm, 3:00pm, etc.), and I would like to flag the timesheetitemID if someone is not within 5 minutes (early or late) of their start or end time. So the table would essentially look like this:

[image: Ex. Flag]

In the 2nd and 3rd timesheetitemIDs you can see that the employee was within 5 minutes of their punch-in, but outside 5 minutes of their punch-out time. I've been learning SQL for the last month and I've hit a road block of sorts with this.

Basically I need to create a separate table, while also using the logic of recognizing if something should be flagged or not. And if you thought that was easy, well there's more! Employees can take a meal break during the day, so there can be two punch-in and punch-out times for a shift. When someone punches out for a meal if doesn't matter if they leave within 5 minutes of the top of the hour, and the same goes for when they clock back in. So it is important to recognize if a punch-in is the 1st or 2nd of the shift and the same for a punch-out.

The way I see it, it would take a genius to solve this! I would love to see the process of how someone with some SQL wisdom would solve this. Please feel free to ask any questions!

Thank you!

Comment: In the other tables (presumably InPunchEvent and OutPunchEvent), do you indicate whether it is a punch in to start work, or start break, or start overtime, etc... and punchingOut for endOfShift, break, etc?  This would help you to only check records in PunchDtl that are relevant.  Also, if someone is 1 hour late, it seems like currently they would appear on time, since it it not known what time they are supposed to arrive.  Do you track expected start/stop time for each employee in the Employee table?  This would also help you limit the query to search only for relevant data points.

Comment: @AdamWenger since it is just a set of sample data there is no scheduling data attached, but one of the practice problems presents this question. You raise a good point about being an hour late, but I think the purpose of it is to show frequent offenders. So sure, if someone showed up late once then it wouldn't be flagged, but over the course of the month it would show who is frequently late.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure whether you are joking or not. This is an exercise I'm doing though that I could use some help with because it seems like a real-world problem. I could always skip it, but it seems challenging and I'd like to see how someone would solve this.

Comment: It sounds less like a personal project and more like homework now.  The problem is interesting enough as homework, but there really isn't enough data in the set to be dealt with cleanly.  I would want to see set schedules, what types of check-ins they're doing, etc... It's simple enough to see if the minutes on a date are between 5 and 55 (your sample late values) but without more details, I wouldn't have a lot of confidence with that answer.

Comment: Okay, well since it seems like no one is willing to give it a try maybe you could help me with even recognizing if the minutes on a datetime are between 5 and 55 minutes?

Comment: @Walker I'll pull my comment.  I've noticed on SO that questions with code get more help.

Comment: @Walker, use the [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function.  You'll be able to get a lot of the basic help with googling.  Paul is also right, If you show the SO community your code, and that you have attempted to solve the problem on your own, you have a better chance of someone wanting to assist.

Comment: You'll need to know what they should have worked (Scheduled), what they worked (Actual) and the segments they were in while at work (BREAK, LUNCH, PRODUCTIVE etc). I'd be really tempted to thrash out the logic for this in a script (e.g. Perl/Python - whatever you fancy); rather than jumping straight into the SQL. Maybe go through each employee one by one, and each of their productive/non-productive segments on a given date - printing it out time diff to the terminal. Once you know what your data looks like (and how you worked it out) - you'll be in a better place to plan your table & SQL

Answer (score 1):

Your first step would be to identify the first punch-in of the shift.  As others have commented, you would most likely need to compare this to some sort of schedule.  In the simplest case, where every employee works a schedule starting in the morning and ending in the evening, you could identify the first punch-in of each day:

```
Select EmployeeID
, cast(Actual_punchInTime as Date) as Day
, Min(Actual_punchInTime) as FirstPunchTime
From MyTable
Group by EmployeeID
, cast(Actual_punchInTime as Date) as Day
```

Then you could use `datepart` to find out how far off the hour the stamp was, like so:

```
Select *
, Case when Datepart(minute, FirstPunchTime) between 5 and 55 
         then 1 
       else 0 end as OffTheHourFlag
```